# Disable Launch URL in OneSignal Push Notification when opened

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, onesignal

Unable to disable the launch url in OneSignal push notification when opened. Tried toggling kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL from true to false and it still opens up Safari.

What can I do to completely remove the launch Url? Thanks in advance.

My code in for OneSignal app.component.ts is as follows,

```js
if (this.appConfig.Onesignal_Enable == true) {
        this.oneSignal.startInit(this.appConfig.OneSignal_AppID, this.appConfig.GCM_SenderID);
        this.oneSignal.iOSSettings({
          kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false,
          kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: true,
        });

        this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
          // do something when a notification is opened
          this.navCtrl.navigateForward('positions');
        });
        this.oneSignal.endInit();
      }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to deep-link into your app? If so, we have docs on how to do that by passing in `additional data` to your notification

Comment: Deep link yes but it's been achieved with the Router or NavigateForward. What I am actually looking at is to completely disable the webview when the push notification is opened, the WordPress post is automatically loaded on the webview when the app is opened after the notification is opened. @RodrigoGomez-Palacio Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it on the web side instead with PHP. For anyone running on WordPress, this is a great filter.

```html
add_filter( 'onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4 );
function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    // Set player ids as subscribed to onesignal notification (see users in onesignal dashboard)
    $fields['isAndroid'] = true;
    $fields['isIos'] = true;
    $fields['isAnyWeb'] = false;
    $fields['isChrome'] = false;
    $fields['data'] = array(
        "myappurl" => $fields['url']
    );
    /* Unset the URL to prevent opening the browser when the notification is clicked */
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```